# Not all in-apps payments enrolled

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using in-apps purchases in my iOS application, also I am using Flurry Analytics to control different user events. So I have one event after

```
- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
```

And with it I can check how many purchases were made ​​daily.
The problem is: in analytics I have 6-8 payments daily, but in my apple account (in Sales->In-Apps) I see only few of them (5 payments from 8 logged, for example).
Any ideas why this payments are missing? Maybe in-apps hack or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the In-App hack.
Below is the one possible scenario if your In-App purchase is kind of Non-Consumable.

- User had already purchased the In-App & after deleting application if he will re-install & again do the In-App purchase then I think it will not be displayed on the apple account(in Sales->In-Apps).